# VBA : Else Statement - what is the correct Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in here in Stackoverflow I tried to create a VBA Code.

I have these set of data that I wanted to create a macro(vba) for this so here is the scenario and code.

it is something like vlook up without a formula

The Column A is the lookup value, The column E and F is the table array, The Column F is the column index

---

```
Sub Nested()
Dim i As Integer
Dim prodID As String
Dim nRows As Integer


For i = 0 To nRows - 1

prodID = Range(a3).Offset(i, 0).Value
rng = Range(“B3”).Offset(i, 0).Value

If rng = "1" Then

If rng <= 1 Then
Range(“C3”).Offset(i, 0).Value = Range(“F1”).Value

ElseIf rng > 1 Then
Range(“C3”).Offset(i, 0).Value = Range(“F2”).Value


End If

End Sub
```

This is the template

[image]

I try to figure out what is the correct for this but I couldn't find it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi @AntiDrondert I have added an image https://www.mediafire.com/view/erifgxqb9ndi731/Capture.JPG/file

I tried to add macro for this and it seems i got an error saying "Block if without end if"

Comment: I wanted to apply in all column selected

Comment: If you were to indent your code, you would quickly see that you are missing an `End If` and a `Next i` from your various statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but you need to populate the `nRows` variable.

```
Sub Nested()

    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, nRows As Long, prodID As String

    For i = 0 To nRows - 1

        prodID = Range("A3").Offset(i, 0).Value
        rng = Range("B3").Offset(i, 0).Value

        Select Case True
            Case rng <= 1:
                Range("C3").Offset(i, 0).Value = Range("F1").Value

            Case rng > 1:
                Range("C3").Offset(i, 0).Value = Range("F2").Value

            Case Else:
                'Rng = 1 - do nothing
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello kostas K i could not get code yet this is something similar with v lookup The Column A is the lookup value
the column E and F is the table array
the Column F is the column index